# Ruby - Proc.call - catching exceptions

Tags: ruby, proc, rescue

I have problem with catching exceptions and errors from calling `Proc object`. See my code:

```
def method1
  .. do something ...
end

def method2
.. do something ...
end

def run_method_safely(proc_obj)
  begin
    proc_obj.call
  rescue => e
    puts "Error man!"
    ... do something ...
  end
end
```

I have few methods (here I have just `method1, method2` but in code i have much more methods) which are run by method `run_method_safely`. I'm doing that this way because I don't want to have every method in begin-rescue block so I wrote method what takes care about that. See:

```
.
run_method_safely(Proc.new { method1 })
run_method_safely(Proc.new { method2 })
.
```

The problem is when `proc_obj.call` is executed with error (method is missing, Webdriver - no such element found or whatever) **rescue block is not executed, program is running like nothing happened**.

Does anybody know how to catch errors and exceptions from Proc code?

Comment: Can you produce a runnable sample that reproduces this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your sample is correct?

```
def safe(proc)
  begin
    proc.call
  rescue
    puts "error"
  end
end

def m1
  puts "m1"
  raise
end

def m2
  puts "m2"
end

safe(Proc.new { m1 })
safe(Proc.new { m2 })
```

Prints

```
m1
error
m2
```

for me.

Btw: you do not need to wrap the call in a Proc, you can pass the `Method` object directly.

```
safe(method(:m1))
```

Comment: Or - even more directly - pass a block, i.e. `safe { m1 }`

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be

```
rescue Exception => e
```

The default for rescue is not to catch **all** errors, but only those which are derived from `StandardError`.

Side note: I was not aware that the syntax

```
rescue => e
```

is valid. `=>` is a binary operator, and you don't provide a left argument for this.

Comment: `=>` isn't an operator at all. Do you mean `<=` or `>=`?

Comment: Doesn't it count as *operator*? In any case, it is used inside a hash, to separate key from values. `{ 'key' => 'value',....}`. I shouldn't have called it operator; it's more like punctuation mark, but one which requires something on both sides...

Comment: I believe the correct term is *punctuator*. Anyway as you now know it has two different meanings.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to rescue from Exception as it's reserved for things like Interrupt when we hit Ctrl-C, and NoMemoryError. In the side note it would correctly rescue from standard error, not exception. Ref: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/rescue-standarderror-not-exception