# How to catch execption for proc in Ruby

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I am using [cap-ext-parallelize gem](https://github.com/roidrage/cap-ext-parallelize) for parallel execution of the cap task for Capistrano

The parallelize method creates sessions which are passes as proc to a wrapper I have written to catch any exceptions that occur inside the session

```
parallelize do |session|
  session.run {deploy.restart} 
  session.run {queue.restart}
  session.run {daemon.restart}
end
```

Below is the wrapper code

```
def parallel_execution(thread_session, function_name)
  begin
    thread_session
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "[Error] #{function_name} failed with error #{e.message}"
    raise e.class, "[Error] #{function_name} failed with error #{e.message}"
  end
end
```

Below is wrapper invocation

```
parallelize do |session|
  parallel_execution(session.run {deploy.restart}, "deploy.restart")
  parallel_execution(session.run {queue.restart}, "queue.restart")
  parallel_execution(session.run {daemon.restart}, "daemon.restart")
end
```

I want to catch any exceptions that occur inside the individual session

The wrapper continues even when there is an exception inside a session

I have tried to print the values

the sessions get passed as an Array to the wrapper and the array elements are proc

so basically I will need a way to catch exception inside a proc block

I came across this question [ruby-proc-call-catching-exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736090/ruby-proc-call-catching-exceptions) but it does not give a way to catch exceptions in [proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Proc.html)

Comment: Recscuing exceptions with a proc is not the difficult part. It's fitting it into your parallelized workflow that's the challenge. Search a bit about exception handling with threads.

Comment: @maxpleaner The individual method that thread calls have error handling in place and same is forwarded to the the error trace on the thread, but some of these methods do not have error handling and we need a generic way to catch the errors in the log trace so I had written this wrapper 

I get proc in the  thread_session array and not my wrapper error handling is not working even when proc raises an error

So need a way to handle errors for proc

Comment: What is this `begin; thread_session` supposed to do? Are you trying to call the `thread_session` proc in there? That's not how that works. With the code `parallel_execution(session.run {deploy.restart}, "deploy.restart")` you are passing the _result_ of `session.run` to `parallel_execution` ... you're _not_ passing `session.run` as a proc here.

Comment: That is exactly that I want to achieve to send session.run as a proc to parallel_execution

Comment: Just wrap it inside a `-> { } ` lambda expression and use `.call` to run it when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a different approach here

Wrapper Method

```
def parallel_execution(thread_session)
  begin
    eval thread_session
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "[Error] #{function_name} failed with error #{e.message}"
    raise "[Error] #{thread_session} failed with error #{e.message}"
end
```

end

Wrapper invocation

```
parallelize do |session|
  session.run { parallel_execution("deploy.restart") }
  session.run { parallel_execution("queue.restart") }
  session.run { parallel_execution("daemon.restart") }
end
```

I passed the Rake task as a string to the wrapper and using eval I invoked the rake task